# PHP text manipulation library

Tags: php, class, text-manipulation

I am developing in a web application that its main function is text manipulation. As you know PHP even does not support Unicode internally. (There is some elementry solution, `mbstring` extension and `u` modifier in `preg_*`)

Is there any library that can make string manipulation a little better?

I found [this class](https://github.com/alecgorge/PHP-String-Class) but is there any other option.

Comment: The mb_* set of functions?

Comment: PHP 5.4 now defaults to UTF-8 http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php

Comment: @MathieuImbert currently I use it mb_ but I am looking for a better and OO solution.

Comment: PHP's supported multibyte since 4.4.3/5.1.3 with the mb_*() functions...

Comment: @MarcB fully Unicode support is planed for PHP 6.

Comment: @PHPst - where and when did you read about PHP 6? Was it in the apocryphal gospels?